# String Replace Based On Variable Value

Tags: java, string, replace

I've the following string: `{"array 1":[ ....`
And I would like to remove everything preceding `[`.

For that I use: `.replace("{\"array 1\":", "");` and that works well.

However, I've several arrays, so I'd like to do the replace based on a variable that holds the array name.

For example:

```
 String arr_name = "array 1";
 ....replace('{\"arr_name\":", "");
```

Is it possible to use variable key to replace a string?

EDIT:

I've ended up adding another element to parse the array in JSON which removed its name.

Thank you all for the quick comments and suggestions.

Comment: You said you want to replace everything before the `[`. Why don't you do exactly that? Why look for the actual array names?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a substring starting at the index of `[`?

Comment: You data odly looks like JSON. Why not just parse it and then extract the values you want?

Comment: That said, all you need to do is concatenate the static parts around the array name, and then replace: `String prefixToRemove = "{\"" + arrayName + "\":[";`

Comment: @RealSkeptic , you are right. What's the best tool for that?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, array names change, so sub string length might cause issues. I'd rather remove it.

Comment: @litelite, it is JSON. It's already parsed.

Comment: @Simply_me Then why are you doing it like that when you could just retrieve the value associated to the correct key?

Comment: If it's json using the parser would be the best way. If it's the only element in the object, just get iterate the object and get the first element. If not, you should [edit] the question and show the general structure of the json.

Comment: @Simply_me I didn't say anything about length... See my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do a string format, here is an example of that :

```
 String arr_name = "array 1";
 ....replace(String.format ("{\"%s\"", arr_name), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a substring, starting at the index of `[`.

```
    String input =  "{\"array 1\":[key:value...";
    String result = input.substring(input.indexOf('['));
```

This gives `[key.value...`